# groups username showing root as group but not allowed to remove

Tags: linux, ubuntu, celery, airflow

I am working on Apache Airflow docker. The default user `airflow` is member of group `root` and `airflow` by default. The output of `groups airflow` command is as below:

```
+ groups airflow
airflow : root airflow
```

However, when I try to remove the `airflow` user from group `root` it fails.

```
+ gpasswd -d airflow root
gpasswd: user 'airflow' is not a member of 'root'
Removing user airflow from group root
```

What could be the reason behind this?

PS: The main issue I am trying to solve here is that log file is not accessible by Airflow master - It seems to be a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow user should belong to group `root` and it should be the main group of the user. This is in order to make the Airflow Image openshift-compatible and it is described here why: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#allowing-arbitrary-user-to-run-the-container

Your permission problem is likely caused by something else. Maybe you are not using the original "entrypoint" of the image when you run your container (it sets umask properly so that any folders and files created by airflow are "group writeable".

You have to make sure that however you access those logs and files they are accessed also by a user who belongs to the "root" group - this way it will be both read and write accessible.